# RoomやRealmを用いた写真の保存方法について

Tags: realm, kotlin

解決したいこと
写真付きのメモ帳アプリを作りたいと考えています。写真データを
RoomやRealmを用いてデータベースに保存し、RecyclerViewで表示する方法を
ご教示いただけないでしょうか。または参考になりそうなサイトを教えていただくか、
データを共有頂けると大変助かります。
多数の本やウェブを調べてみましたが下記のような写真なしのメモ帳の
作り方を紹介するものはあっても、写真付きのものを紹介するものはありません。
https://hima-engineer.com/2021/01/27/%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E5%B8%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%EF%BC%81/

自分で試したこと
以下の方法を試してみましたが、これだけでは不完全なようでビルドできませんでした。
https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/store-image-in-sqlite-in-android-with-room-database

その他
以下サイトにおいても質問をしていますのでご承知おきください。
https://qiita.com/koheigithub/questions/9f4689e4d24a58be37e0
https://teratail.com/questions/361177

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/361177) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。参考URLもつけていただきとても助かりました。ご指摘の通り内容を補足いたしました。